# DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort a list of names in alphabetical order. I thought that I would be able to do it on my LINQ statement but this didn't turn out the case and it brought me an error. Does anybody know why this is the case and how to fix this?

Here is my join:

```
 public IQueryable<Supplier> GetAllSuppliersByClientWithClaims(int ClientID) {
            return (from s in db.Suppliers
                    where s.ClientID == ClientID
                    join h in db.Headers on new { a = s.ClientID, b = s.SupplierID } equals new { a = h.ClientID, b = h.SupplierID }
                    orderby s ascending
                    select s);
        }
```

Here is the dropdown for the view:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportTypeOptions.First().ReportID, new SelectList(Model.ReportTypeOptions, "ReportID", "ReportName"), "Select Report", new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD", onchange="myFunction()"})
```

Comment: On which field you want sort ascending ??

Comment: I would like to sort on the SupplierName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make an order by on your `entity`.

You should do it on one of the `property` of your `entity`

```
orderby s.SupplierName
```

or multiple properties, of course :

```
 orderby s.SupplierName, 
         s.SupplierLastName,
         s.SupplierBirthDate descending
```